# Using in statement in APEX Interactive Report

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm trying to create an Interactive Report where the where
statement has an in clause.

Some like this.

```
Select column1,
       column2, 
       column3
from Table
where column1 in (1,2,3)
```

Column 1 is a number field in Oracle.

It works if there is only one value,
but if there are multiples that are comma
separated, then I get an ORA-01722: invalid number.

Is this not valid syntax in an APEX Interactive Report...

Comment: I suppose that your actual where clause looks like `WHERE column1 IN (:P1_SOME_ITEM)` ?

Comment: Yes, Sorry I left that out. I've tried application items and page items.  It's the same issue when there is more than one value.

Comment: also, the values are comma separated, that are stored in P1_SOME_ITEM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not valid SQL - a common problem with a number of solutions. Here's one that uses regular expressions
https://blogs.oracle.com/aramamoo/entry/how_to_split_comma_separated_string_and_pass_to_in_clause_of_select_statement